# How do I use trac AuthzPolicy to restrict access to repository browser?

Tags: trac

Trac is configured with multiple subversion repositories

http://trac.company.com/trac/browser/

REPO1
REPO2
REPO3

Currently staff access this as anonymous.  I am adding a new repository UTILITIES that I don't want anonymous users to be able to see.

This is where [`AuthzPolicy`](https://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracFineGrainedPermissions#AuthzPolicy) comes in, but I am really struggling to get it working.

In `trac.ini` I have

```
[trac]
...
permission_policies = AuthzPolicy,
  ReadonlyWikiPolicy,
  DefaultPermissionPolicy,
  LegacyAttachmentPolicy

[components]
...
tracopt.perm.authz_policy.* = enabled


[authz_policy]
authz_file = /var/trac/conf/authzpolicy.conf
```

But I am unable to figure out what I need to add in `authzpolicy.conf` to block `BROWSER_VIEW` from anonymous.  I have tried (various combinations of):

```
[*]
* = !BROWSER_VIEW
anonymous = !BROWSER_VIEW

[repository:*]
* = !BROWSER_VIEW
anonymous = !BROWSER_VIEW

[repository:UTILITIES*]
* = !BROWSER_VIEW
anonymous = !BROWSER_VIEW
```

Nothing I seem to add in there, blocks an anonymous user from browsing any repositories. The relevant bits from debug log don't really shed any light either:

```
2019-09-19 12:33:19,518 Trac[authz_policy] DEBUG: Parsing authz security policy /var/trac/conf/authzpolicy.conf
2019-09-19 12:33:19,519 Trac[authz_policy] DEBUG: Checking BROWSER_VIEW on repository:UTILITIES@*/source:/@68
2019-09-19 12:33:19,521 Trac[authz_policy] DEBUG: Checking BROWSER_VIEW on repository:UTILITIES@*/source:/tags@68
2019-09-19 12:33:19,523 Trac[authz_policy] DEBUG: Checking BROWSER_VIEW on repository:UTILITIES@*/source:/branches@68
2019-09-19 12:33:19,524 Trac[authz_policy] DEBUG: Checking BROWSER_VIEW on repository:UTILITIES@*/source:/trunk@68
...
2019-09-19 12:33:19,628 Trac[authz_policy] DEBUG: Checking CHANGESET_VIEW on repository:UTILITIES@*/changeset:1@*
2019-09-19 12:33:19,636 Trac[authz_policy] DEBUG: Checking CHANGESET_VIEW on repository:UTILITIES@*/changeset:68@*
```

If I remove `BROWSER_VIEW` from anonymous in the `DefaultPermissionPolicy` then nothing can browse repositories, even when I put the following in `authzpolicy.conf`.

```
[*]
* = *
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue turned out to be permissions on `/var/trac/conf/authzpolicy.conf` I needed to give the web server read access

```
$ chgrp apache /var/trac/conf/authzpolicy.conf
$ chmod 640 /var/trac/conf/authzpolicy.conf
```

Once that issue was resolved I started to see different behaviour based on permissions configured, and finally came up with the following for what I needed

```
[repository:UTILITIES@*]
john = BROWSER_VIEW
* = !BROWSER_VIEW

[repository:*@*]
john = !BROWSER_VIEW
* = BROWSER_VIEW
```

John can see UTILITIES but not the other repositories, and anonymous can see all repositories except UTILITIES.

I realise that John can log out and see the other repositories. The main aim was to prevent anonymous users seeing the UTILITIES repository.

Comment: You might want to look at using [AuthzSourcePolicy](https://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracFineGrainedPermissions#AuthzSourcePolicy), as the same configuration file can be used for restricting view access to the Trac repository browser and SVN. AuthzPolicy will only restrict view access to the Trac repository browser, and can also be used for other realms in Trac (e.g. wiki, milestone).

Comment: I had a quick look at `AuthzSourcePolicy` but it seemed geared towards trac hosting a single repository or at least a single authz file. Our trac hosts multiple repositories with separate authz files for each. It didn't look like it was going to be easy to get that to work.

Comment: Currently only a single authz file is supported, see [#12442](https://trac.edgewall.org/ticket/12442). However, multiple repositories in a single authz file are supported, see [Trac Configuration section](https://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracFineGrainedPermissions#TracConfiguration).